# Trouble working out course work module precentages.

Tags: problem-solving, percentages

So I have a bit of a maths problem. I'm looking to organise my learning for my apprenticeship into a spread sheet. Where I can log my personal learning hours against the expected learning hours, keep track of the total percentages of each of the modules and have it set up to automatically add the total as I go along but I am not mathematically minded and even though I have tried to work it out myself using various methods I searched on the internet. I just can't seem to crack it myself. So if you could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

So my course has 12 modules each with their own credit values which add to a total of 60 credits which would be 100% of my course completed at the end of the apprenticeship.

So at this point in time my course as a whole is 12% completed and I have contributed work to four of my modules so far.

Unit 1 - Credit value 4 - Percentage completed 34%

Unit 6 - Credit value 6 - Percentage completed 37%

Unit 38 - Credit value 2 - Percentage completed 100%

Unit 63 - Credit value 3 - Percentage completed 11%

So what I have been told to do was something similar to this;

You have "62% of 30%" and "65% of 70%"; whenever you see "(quantity) of (quantity)" you have to multiply, and so overall you got
60/100 x 30/100 + 65/100 x 70/100 x 100
 ...which is 64.1% overall.

But I don't seem to be able to apply this to my course work and I've been working on this spread sheet for a couple of hours now and this seems to be my only hiccup with it so far.

I know it's not a lot of information to go on but if anyone could help or point me in the right direction that would be great thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have completed $0.34\cdot4+0.37\cdot6+1.00\cdot2+0.11\cdot3=5.91$ credits so far. That is the same as $5.91/60=.0985=9.85\%$ of your total course work.